# how to make div toggle onclick, child div(s) have no id's

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I write Javascript/jQuery that hides a particular div onclick and makes the other divs visible.

For example, clicking on div:1 would make div:1 invisible and div:2 and div:3 visible if they were invisible.

```
<div id="foo">
    <div>a</div>
    <div>b</div>
    <div>c</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sravsk/SSwJC/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#foo > div').on('click',function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).siblings().show();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SSwJC/4/

Comment: True, but this is a bit less obfuscated. Rather use up an extra line so Sravsk is sure to understand =)

Comment: I have no control over css just the jquery, so the answer from jake is right on !

Comment: You don't need the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector) selector; if the `div` *isn't* visible, how could it be clicked?

Comment: ^ true - that's a remnant from the first version of this that I wrote. Forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/SSwJC/5/

```
 $("#foo > div").click(function(){
       $('.invisible').removeClass('invisible');
       $(this).addClass('invisible');
 });  

#foo > div {
   cursor: pointer;
}

.invisible { display:none;}
```